# Why do alias foo1="echo $1" and alias foo2="echo '$1'" behave as they do?

Tags: bash, echo, whitespace, alias

In my `.bashrc` file, I put the following two lines:

```
alias foo1="echo $1"
alias foo2="echo '$1'"
```

Then, in the terminal, I get the following output:

```
$ foo1 hello world
hello world
$ foo2 hello world
 hello world
```

Why is the extra space produced by `foo2`?

If I just do the following in terminal, the outputs are as shown:

```
$ echo hello world
hello world
$ echo 'hello world'
hello world
```

This leads me to think that `foo1` and `foo2` should do exactly the same thing. How come they do not actually output exactly the same thing, and why do they differ by simply one space character?

(Also, why do either of them output `world`? I would expect only the first argument to be outputted.)

Comment: Running `set -x` is useful here, in terms of seeing what actually happens.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy what does `set -x` do and what would be the usage to help see what is happening here?

Comment: Turns on logging of the commands the shell runs to stderr, so when you run `set -x` and then `foo2 hello world`, you see the `echo` command it invokes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ah I see how this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Note that if you put `set -- "first argument" "second argument"` *before* your alias definitions, the result of your commands change. (After the definitions, they make no difference unless you change your quoting types). That said, for any real-world use, the right answer to pretty much any and every question about shell aliases is to pretend they don't exist and use functions instead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What would it look like to use a function instead here?

Comment: `foo() { echo "$@"; }` is a function which passes all of `foo`'s arguments through to `echo`, each as an individual string not subject to string-splitting or globbing. Does that answer your question? (`foo() { echo "$1"; }` passes through only the first argument, discarding the others).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes this makes sense. Then if I do `foo() { echo "$1"; }` and type `foo hello world` then I will only get `hello` outputted, which is what I expected (I was also unclear earlier why `foo1` and `foo2` outputted `world` at all, but now I see why).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If, in a typical interactive shell, you run:

```
$ set --             # this clears the argument list; it's empty by default, but make sure.
$ alias foo1="echo $1"
$ alias foo2="echo '$1'"
$ alias -p
```

The output of `alias -p` is as follows:

```
$ alias -p
alias foo1='echo '
alias foo2='echo '\'''\'''
```

Notably, the `$1`s are not present at all -- because you defined the alias in a double-quoted string, they were replaced with the current value of `$1` -- the value present in the current shell's context, which for an interactive shell is going to be empty at startup.

---

Thus, when you run:

```
foo2 hello world
```

...what the shell invokes is:

```
echo '' hello world
```

Because `echo` puts spaces between its arguments, this prints out as:

```
 hello world
```

---

Whereas, if you run:

```
foo1 hello world
```

...what the shell invokes is:

```
echo hello world
```

...because, as you can see in the `foo1` alias emitted by `alias -p`, there is no record of the unquoted `$1` left; it was replaced with its current value -- an empty string -- at definition time.

Comment: You mentioned defining the alias in a double-quoted string. What difference does it make if I defined it using a single-quoted string instead?

Comment: @Grayscale, if you ran `alias foo1='echo $1'`, then the `$1` is not expanded when the alias is defined, but is instead expanded when the alias is -- so in that case, `set -- 'new value for $1'` will change the alias's result even if it's done *after* the definition (but before the invocation).

Answer (score 3):

aliases do not take positional arguments. `$1` will evaluate to nothing inside an alias. `foo2` is literally appending what you typed after `foo2` to the empty string `''`, which includes the space after `foo2`. `foo1` is not appending to anything as `$1` evaluates to nothing, so the space is not shown.

Comment: @Arount, it is not wrong. [See here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3773/how-to-pass-parameters-to-an-alias).